# My ul floats right in all screen sizes except large desktop?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to have a nav bar that floats on the right. It floats right for a medium sized screen but any bigger it goes back to the left. I am at a loss of how to get this to float to the right.

The issue is with the id category-words-nav.

Things I tried:

- Using the media query to make the ul float right on the min-width: 991px / max-width: 1999px
- floating the specific ul to the right
- floating all uls in the category-header to the right

After trying these, the nav still stays on the left when the screen is at max on my desktop. But once I start to shrink the screen, the ul will jump to the right where it is supposed to be.

```css
#category-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  background: black;
}

#category-header ul li a:link,
#category-header ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
}

#category-header ul#category-words-nav {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

#category-header ul#category-icons-nav {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

#category-header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

Media Queries @media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1999px) {}


/*=== Tablet ===*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  #top-header ul#tablet-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #top-header ul#desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #top-header ul li {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  #category-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-words-nav {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-words-nav li {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
}


/*=== Phone ===*/

@media (max-width:767px) {
  #top-header {
    display: flex;
  }
  #top-header ul#tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #top-header ul#desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #category-words-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #category-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-icons-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-icons-nav li {
    font-size: 4.1vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="category-header">
  <nav>
    <ul id="category-words-nav">
      <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BOYS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GIRLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CUSTOMIZE</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="category-icons-nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: your code is working fine....what is the issue...?

Comment: Thats the thing, I don't know why it was doing that. I put the code into codepen and it worked just fine there too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Maybe you code problem with insert meta tag and media query writeup

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #category-words-nav {float:left !important;} //media query
}
```

```css
#category-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  background: black;
}

#category-header ul li a:link,
#category-header ul li a:visited {
  color: white;
}

#category-header ul#category-words-nav {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

#category-header ul#category-icons-nav {
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

#category-header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1999px) {}


/*=== Tablet ===*/

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
  #top-header ul#tablet-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #top-header ul#desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #top-header ul li {
    font-size: 3vw;
  }
  #category-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-words-nav {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-words-nav li {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
  }
}


/*=== Phone ===*/

@media (max-width:767px) {
  #top-header {
    display: flex;
  }
  #top-header ul#tablet-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #top-header ul#desktop-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-inner {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #category-words-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #category-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-icons-nav {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #category-header ul#category-icons-nav li {
    font-size: 4.1vw;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #category-words-nav {
    float: left !important;
  } //media query
}
```

```html
<header id="category-header">
  <nav>
    <ul id="category-words-nav">
      <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">BOYS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GIRLS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CUSTOMIZE</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="category-icons-nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```